# Fetching near-realtime data from external API

Tags: php, shell, laravel-5, cron, web-worker

I'm looking for a sustainable solution to fetch data every *x* seconds (let's say 20) and store it in a relational database using PHP. After doing some research I found a few options:

**1) Cronjobs (with shell scripts)**

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/800/how-to-run-scripts-every-5-seconds for more information. This basically comes down to run a shell script (looping/sleeping)

This doesn't feel right as I could not catch exceptions and/or race conditions might occur. Also, cronjobs itself are not made for this kind of tasks.

**2) Web-worker (with queued jobs)**

Laravel provides a [queue worker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#running-the-queue-worker) that can process new jobs (asynchronously) as they are pushed onto the queue. I could push multiple (say a lot) of jobs to the queue at once which should processed every *x* seconds consecutively.

This sounds like a more robust solution as I could catch exceptions and make sure the worker is running (using observers). The downside; it's slower and it might be overengineered.

**3) Web socket**

I could use node.js to run a websocket client like [socket.io](https://socket.io/) and implement some kind of timing mechanism to store the data every *x* seconds.

This solution feels  odd as I was taught that sockets are used to push data to clients (realtime), but I have never seen that they were used to insert data.

---

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are [artisan commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#writing-commands).

You would start by creating a command:

```
php artisan make:command FetchData
```

This creates a `FetchData` class. In this class you can edit the `handle` function.

```
public function handle()
{
    //fetch your data here
}
```

You also need to edit the `$signature` variable.

```
protected $signature = 'fetch:data';
```

The next step is to register the command in the `Kernel.php` in the Console namespace.
You need to add your newly created `FetchData` class to the `$commands` array.

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\FetchData::class
];
```

You could now call this command from the console like `php artisan fetch:data`

After you registered your command in the `Kernel.php` you can [schedule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling) this command.

You start by adding following line to your crontab on your server (type crontab -e)

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

You can now add following command to the `schedule` function in the `Kernel.php`:

```
$schedule->command('fetch:data')->everyThirtyMinutes();
```

There is no option for a job to run every twenty minutes so in this example I chose thirty minutes. You can check the available options [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#defining-schedules).

Comment: The problem is that I need to retrieve data every *x* seconds and cron only allows for a minimum of one minute.

Comment: @JasonK then a Websocket is probably the best solution.